# Access(SQL) - Count distinct fields and group by field name

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I am in the middle of making a Client a Access Database and am stuck on how to work around what im doing.

i have a table with somthing like 
i have a table called Observations with somithing like this

```
Error Identified | Error Cat | ... | So on
No               |           |     |
Yes              | Dave3     |     |
Yes              | Dave      |     |
Yes              | Dave3     |     |
Yes              | Dave5     |     |
Yes              | Dave      |     |
Yes              | Dave6     |     |
Yes              | Dave6     |     |
Yes              | Dave      |     |
```

I want to count the number of occurrences that each [Error Cat] where [Error Identified] is yes

so it would bb

```
Error Cat | Count |
Dave      |   3   |
Dave3     |   2   |
Dave5     |   1   |
Dave6     |   2   |
```

What is the Access SQL for this to happen

I tried so hard but it just wont run the SQL 
Please help.

Comment: Have you looked at the **Query Designer**, it makes it very easy to create these sort of queries in Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ErrorCat, COUNT(*) totalCount
FROM tableName
WHERE ErrorIdentified = 'YES'
GROUP BY ErrorCat
```

Comment: Thank you, you missed some out but with tweaks it works thanks.