# Distinct Count Multiple Columns MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I am wanting to find a way to use the following table and write a distinct count query:

```
Unique Number | Name  | Number | ID
1             | James | 1      | 456
2             | John  | 2      | 456
2             | John  | 3      | 456
2             | John  | 4      | 456
2             | John  | 5      | 457
1             | James | 3      | 457
1             | James | 4      | 456
3             | Ted   | 3      | 457
3             | Ted   | 4      | 456
```

And would like the following query result when the ID is 456

```
Unique  | Name  | Number Count
1       | James | 2     
2       | John  | 3      
3       | Ted   | 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access(SQL) - Count distinct fields and group by field name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504991/accesssql-count-distinct-fields-and-group-by-field-name).  The only change to the answer of that question is that you add multiple column names, comma delimited, to the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I am extremely new to access, what would the query look like with adding add the items you mentioned? I am also looking to get a distinct count for the Number column.  Basically I want a query that shows me what is the Distinct Number Count for each Unique Number column and I want to make sure the Name column is listed so I know who the Unique Number is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple aggregate query will get the count of Number by name and ID.

`SELECT [Unique Number], [Name], ID, Count(*) AS CountNum FROM table GROUP BY [Unique Number], [Name], ID;'`

Counting how many unique ID per name requires two queries. First have to do a query that returns DISTINCT IDs for each Name.

`SELECT DISTINCT [Unique Number], [Name], ID FROM tablename;`

Then use that query to calculate aggregate count.

`SELECT [Unique Number], [Name], Count(ID) AS CountID FROM Query1 GROUP BY [Unique Number], [Name];`

Can nest the 2 queries.
`SELECT [Unique Number], [Name], Count(ID) AS CountID FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Unique Number], [Name], ID FROM tablename) AS Query1 GROUP BY [Unique Number], [Name];`